# Tabbed Toolbar in Android L

Tags: android, tabs, android-actionbar, toolbar, android-5.0-lollipop

So I'm a complete noob when it comes to Android and I've found different tutorials on how to migrate from an ActionBar to a Toolbar, but I can't understand them fully.

What I want is a Toolbar similar to the Shazam app, that is, without a title and only tabs.

Can anyone guide me to a tutorial or demo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Toolbar` does not support tabs. You will need to use some other solution, such as:

- `ViewPager` and a tabbed indicator (`PagerTabStrip`, `SlidingPagerTabStrip`, `TabPageIndicator` from the ViewPagerIndicator library, etc.).
- `FragmentTabHost`